# No Maven tab in NetBeans IDE / jMonkey SDK

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jmonkeyengine

I want to use some Maven-supported libraries in jMonkey SDK. jMonkey SDK is based on NetBeans. I found, that it has no Maven configuration tab in `Tools->Options->Miscellaneous`. I thought that it is because Maven plugin was not installed. So, I have installed it. Unfortunately it didn't change anything: Maven configuration tab still absent.

How to accomplish? How to configure Maven in jMonkey SDK and use it in parallel with jMonkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven options were moved under Java category, instead of Miscellaneous.